# Is using SAML bearer tokens for authenticating users to backend services a bad idea?

Tags: authentication, authorization, saml, claims-based-identity, acs

Suppose I have a front-end application that wants to fetch some data from a back-end service. (I do.) The service will need to verify that the end-user is authenticated, that it is authorized to use the service and possibly filter the returned data based on the user's privileges. In my case, both the front-end app and the back-end service relies on Azure ACS for authentication.

[image: Simple federated identity scenario]

Ideally the front-end would like to *act on the behalf of* the authenticated user, which sounds like a good fit for using an `ActAs` token (as specified in WS-Trust). However, it turns out that [ACS does not currently support ActAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296421/is-identity-delegation-via-ws-trust-actas-supported-in-acs/11298814#11298814).

A workaround could be to *use the actual bearer token* (the bootstrap token in the front-end app) to authenticate to the back-end service. [It's not hard to do](http://travisspencer.com/blog/2012/01/authenticating-to-a-wcf-servic.html), but would it be a bad idea for some reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your front-end app, you could certainly pass along the identity data of the end user by either sending the token as is or sending the attributes from it. Both have issues. For the former, if it's also encrypted, the front- and back-ends will have to share the private key needed to decrypt it; they will also have to share audience restrictions, etc. in order for the back-end to consider the token valid for it. In other words, the front- and back-ends will be ONE relying party, not two. Might not be a problem, but be aware. In the latter case, you end up sending user data in a proprietay way which could increase integration and maintenance costs over time. In both cases, you can authenticate the front-end app to the back-end using some other type of credential, e.g., a certificate used at the transport level and, thus, forming a trusted subsystem between them.

One thing that I would suggest you consider instead is OAuth 2. From [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adventurousidentity/archive/2011/09/18/acs-v2-oauth-2-0-delegation-support-explained.aspx), it seems to me that ACS supports it (though I don't have any first hand experience w/ it). The truely wonderful thing about OAuth 2 is that it bakes delegation in, and is NO WHERE near as complex as ActAs in WS-Trust. The net result is the same, i.e., the back-end service will have info about the calling service and the end user, but the amount of effort to get it setup in incomparable. The tokens will still be bearer tokens, but you can mitigate that to a degree by using SSL. Beyond SSL, you can put some additional measures in place, but the best, IMO, would be if Microsoft did something in ACS like Google has done w/ their Access Tokens for service accounts which uses asymmetric keys that are chained up to a PKI. (BTW, for all I know, Microsoft may have already done something like that; if so, you're set.)

Anyway, HTH!

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot! Will have a look at OAuth 2, then, to see if I can get a spike up and running. I guess it's easy to get seduced by the tooling support for ActAs in Windows Identity Foundation and WCF, it makes it look so simple (and it *is* simple as long as you're using .NET+WCF and don't have to peek under the hood of things). Could be problematic with regards to portability though. Down the rabbit hole I go...