# How do I pass the principal provided by Azure ACS in an MVC application to a WCF service?

Tags: azure, wcf-security, azure-acs

So, I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application to be hosted in Azure. It's currently authenticating users via Azure ACS which delegates to a number of IdPs of clients for the application.

The application now needs to call into a WCF service to display some information, but the services need to be secured. I had originally though to use the WS-Trust protocol and pass the identity through the application using an "ActAs" token, however [Azure ACS 2.0 will not issue tokens of this type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296421/is-identity-delegation-via-ws-trust-actas-supported-in-acs/11298814#11298814).

How can I obtain an access token for the services based on the user's current identity? I can go back to the ACS for additional tokens, but the system mustn't prompt for the user to provide credentials each time.

Comment: Does this help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Federate-Windows-Live-ID-556ad976?

Comment: I had considered the idea of producing a custom STS, but it seems a very heavy-handed approach.

Comment: Agreed - all of delegating a federated identity looks a bit long-winded. I'm sure you've seen this, which would at least give you an off the shelf start on a custom STS: http://thinktecture.github.com/

Comment: @JcFx You ought to add this stuff as an answer; it's a solution that's worth up-voting, even if I choose not to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way is identity delegation, using a custom STS, as in this example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Federate-Windows-Live-ID-556ad976

To quote from the description:

> In this sample we will walk you through building an application that
>   federates and delegates the Windows Live ID claims. The application
>   makes use of a custom security token service that exposes a
>   WS-Federation passive endpoint (default.aspx) and also exposes a
>   WS-Trust active endpoint (ActAsIssuer.svc). The passive endpoint
>   federates to Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS) and the active
>   endpoint will consume the bootstrap token and issue additional claims
>   for that user. Here is a summarized diagram of the application
>   architecture:
>   [image]

The [ThinkTecture Identity Server](http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/) might give you a leg up in deploying your own custom STS, or the classes in the [IdentityModel](http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/) from the same developer may help - there's a specific set of helpers pertaining to WCF security and WS-Trust. (Links are for the latest versions, for .NET 4.5 - there are earlier versions as well).